# Could this cause a JavaScript memory leak?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I use a couple of functions heavily in my code. Now, as I'm looking for the source of high memory usage, I want to ensure that they're not the culprits.

Using jQuery, I bind and trigger custom events on the body element. When an event is triggered, I store it in a list of triggered events. One of the helper functions I use is called "waitfor". Here's some pseudocode:

```
waitfor = function(event, callback){

  if(event_has_ever_been_called){
    callback(); //RUN IMMEDIATELY
  }
  else{
    //BIND CALLBACK TO RUN AS SOON AS THE EVENT IS TRIGGERED
    $("body").bind(event, function(){
      callback();
    });
  }
}
```

For example,

```
//ADD GOOGLE MAP TO PAGE
... listen for the google map 'idle' event, 
... then call $("body").trigger("gmap.ready") 

//ADD MARKERS AS SOON AS POSSIBLE (BUT NOT BEFORE)
waitfor("gmap.ready", function(){
  //add markers
});
```

This seems very straightforward to me but I'm a little concerned that it (or any of my other functions that use anonymous callback functions) could be causing high memory usage.

Is this sufficient information to determine that this function is safe / not safe?

Comment: Are you setting `event_has_ever_been_called somewhere`?

Comment: No, that's what I mean by "pseudocode" -- not actual code, just there to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should call [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one) instead of `bind` to remove the handler after the event fires.

Otherwise, your function, and everything referenced by its closure, will stay referenced forever by jQuery's handler list.

Comment: Good suggestion, SLaks -- I *do* unbind the event after it's called, though.